# uploadComplete event of the sap.ui.unified.FileUploader is not fired

Tags: sapui5

Control definition:

```js
<unified:FileUploader width="300px" id="fileUploader" change="documentChanged" 
    uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete">
```

Function's definition:

```js
handleUploadComplete: function(oEvent) {
    console.log("oUploader complete oEvent----> ",oEvent);
    console.log("oUploader complete oEvent.params----> ",oEvent.getParameters());
}
```

In my upload function:

```js
oUploader.setUploadUrl(sUrl);// url is defined before
oUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
     name: "slug",
     value: encodeURIComponent(oUploader.getValue())
}));
oUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
     name: "x-csrf-token",
     value: this._sToken // defined before
}));
oUploader.setSendXHR(true);
oUploader.upload();
```

The event is just not fired (I have a breakpoint inside the function, and it's not triggered, no `console.log` messages). The file is uploaded fine.

What do I miss? Thanks.

upd: I'm using sapui5 version 1.28.44 and I'm limitied to this version.

Comment: Hi, out of interest. Did the Header Request include the additional parameters you added as above? When I attempt to add to the request header the key-value pairs do not show up

Comment: @Bernard no, just those listed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was destroying the dialog fragment before the `uploadComplete` event could fire.

Case closed.

Comment: exactly what i was doing too. Tx for posting

Answer (score 0):

You can try upload collection . It is work for me.
[Upload Collection](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.UploadCollection/samples)